# Magento2 - How to enlarge the catalog single product image?

Tags: magento2, php

How to Enlarge the catalog single product image in Magento2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the size from xml file in your theme.

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme_name/etc/view.xml`

```
       <image id="product_base_image" type="image">
            <width>265</width>
            <height>265</height>
        </image>
```

If you dont have view.xml in your theme then you will need to add this xml file from your theme parent. if your theme is default luma then you will find view.xml in below path:

`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml`

After that you will need to run below command.

`php bin/magento catalog:images:resize`

Comment: i have made the changes in both view xml file one is from theme and another is from luma theme but still there is no effect

Comment: Did you run the command for image resize. ?

Comment: i have run the command for image resize

Comment: help me on this